# Dual monitors shared between Mac Mini and Windows laptop

Tags: windows-7, mac, multiple-monitors, mac-mini

I have

- a Mac Mini (2011) with HDMI and Thunderbolt
- a laptop with DisplayPort and VGA
- a DisplayPort To HDMI Cable

I want a setup where I am able to easily switch between Mac and Windows, both with dual monitors.

At work I use a DisplayPort to HDMI cable and a VGA cable for dual monitors on my PC.

On a side note, what does a HDMI splitter do? Is it possible to use the HDMI port and an HDMI splitter to get dual monitors with extended display?

Comment: Maybe a dual monitor KVM? (http://www.dualmonitorkvm.com/) You will just want to make sure you have the right adapters and that whatever KVM you choose will support your resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a Dual monitor KVM like [this one](http://www.kvmgalore.com/shopping/product_info.php?products_id=42797).
You will then need to normalize the connector types:

For [HDMI to DVI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FUVNX8), for [Thunderbolt to DVI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005UABJW8), for [Display Port to DVI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017K6BD2), for [VGA to DVI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006HSM2), and then some [KVM cables](http://www.kvmgalore.com/shopping/product_info.php?products_id=20345).

Plug it all in and you can now share your keyboard, mouse, speakers and two monitors between your Mac Mini and your Windows laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You would need some kind of HDMI switch like [THIS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015YWKYY) in order to be able to connect two or more HDMI inputs, and have them connect to a single HDMI output.

Most computer monitors that have VGA and HDMI inputs also have a switch built into them so that if you were to connect two different sources (one to the VGA and one to the HDMI) you could switch between them.

A simple HDMI splitter like [THIS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FMJLQC) works in the opposite way.  It takes a single HDMI source, and splits it so you can send the same exact signal to multiple displays.  It would not suffice for what you want to do.  It has no way for you to differentiate between the two signals to decide which you want to display on the monitor.